# Connect to Blob Storage from Python using Individual Docker Image Deployed as Azure Webapp

Tags: docker, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have a Docker with python which is deployed as webapp on Azure (I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-docker-python-postgresql-app)

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
EXPOSE 2222 80 8080 5000 
COPY daemon.json /etc/docker/
ENV http_proxy http://<LOCALPROXYADDRESS>:8080
ENV https_proxy https://<LOCALPROXYADDRESS>:8080

RUN apt-get update \ 
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
  && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd


COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/


COPY init_container.sh /bin/
RUN chmod 755 /bin/init_container.sh 
CMD ["/bin/init_container.sh"]

COPY app/ /app/
WORKDIR /app
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
CMD flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
```

I try to connect via python to a Blob Storage using BlockBlobService from azure.storage.blob. This works fine for a container started on my local machine. Once I push it to azure, the following error is printed:

```
azure.common.AzureException: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<CONTAINERNAME>.blob.core.windows.net', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: /mycontainer?restype=container 
(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',  
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
0x7fe859467cc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or 
service not known',)))
```

Comment: Is the proxy running on Azure also? I believe there is no proxy which is accessible on your local that's why it doesn't work. Remove `ENV http_proxy http://<LOCALPROXYADDRESS>:8080` and `ENV https_proxy http://<LOCALPROXYADDRESS>:8080`. Build and push the image it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to Azure Blob Storage in Python with `StorageClient.set_proxy` method via Http Proxy, like the code below.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name="<your account name>", account_key="<your account key>")
super(BlockBlobService, block_blob_service).set_proxy("LOCALPROXYADDRESS", "8080")
```

Hope it helps.